# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql, fetchall

I know this question has been asked before but the answers found don't help me to find why my code is not working.

I specify that I use WAMP under Windows, that the name of my database is "myapp" and I am looking for the results of the "posts" table.

My SQL query:

```
"SELECT * FROM `posts`"
```

works with phpMyAdmin.

Nevertheless; I have the message indicated in the title.

My code:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost; dbname = myapp", 'root', '');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts`";
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
var_dump($query);
$posts = $query->fetchAll();
```

For information,

```
var_dump($query);
```

return false

Please help me :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983

Comment: remove spaces from dsn

Comment: try setting this attribute to see the error. `$pdo->setAttribute("PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE", PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Oh my god, it was indeed the spaces in the DSN.
Ty so much.